# How to do version control via ftp?

Tags: linux, version-control, deployment, ftp

I have a web dev. client using a shared host that doesn't allow shell access, and thus no access to SVN, Git, etc. I've tried to convince him to move to one of the many cheap options that allow it, but he won't do it. If I use version control on my staging server, are there any tools that will allow me to replicate the changes to production via ftp? Locally I have both mac & windows, the staging server is linux, so something that works on any of those platforms....

Answer (score 3):

Using your Linux staging server you could keep a separate checked out copy that you use specifically for that host and then use a utility to mirror that directory with the host server.

LFTP is useful for this kind of thing. Its available for most Linux distributions and includes a 'mirror' function:

> Mirror  specified source directory to
>   local target directory. If target
>          directory ends with a slash, the source base name is appended to
>   target
>          directory  name.  Source and/or target can be URLs pointing to
>   directories.

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of ftp mirror software is what you need.  Not tested it but a quick search gave me [this Java application](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576777/).  You could run that over your up-to-date checked out repository.

Answer (score 1):

Good thing for keeping SVN repo and FTP copy in sync is [svn2web](http://svn2web.sourceforge.net/). May I suggest creating separate branch for production copy and do merges to that branch for uploading to production server.

Answer (score 0):

Short of finding / implementing some FUSE based CoW file system that supports immutable versions .. I'd just find another (more developer friendly) host. As far as I know, no FTP server supports this natively, nor can I think of any elegant means of putting it in place with script hackery.

I could be wrong.

Comment: as I said: the client won't move hosts

Comment: @sprugman: Some problems simply can not be solved in their given constraints. You can not write your name on mars, you can not use FTP as a VCS without jumping through hoops. If the FTP server was backed by an http://ext3cow.com partition, you may have a start, and I did at least _try_ to offer some sort of a solution.

Comment: @tinkertim: I tried to un-down-vote you, but it won't let me ('vote too old to be changed'). FWIW, I didn't really read your initial post as a suggestion. The way you wrote it, the thrust to me was: "short of this thing that sounds impossible (given how restrictive this host is), do the thing that you said in your original post you couldn't do", which was why I down-voted.

Comment: @sprugman: no worries :) The first rule about stack overflow is not to talk about stack overflow.

Comment: @sprugman: seriously, no worries. You did cite a specific criteria and I told you it was not likely to work. I don't see a reason to edit my post though, its quite clear if read in its entirety :) I should also mention that I'm terminally blunt.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write a batch file that is able to

1. Export the SVN repository
2. Upload the exported files to your Linux server via FTP

Answer (score 0):

This question (and answer) really helped me just now as I implemented version control via `gitolite` on a separate server and lftp.

Here’s what I did:

1. [Set up `gitolite`](http://silas.sewell.org/blog/2011/01/08/setup-gitolite-on-ubuntu/) on my ubuntu staging server

   1. created base repo (i.e. `foo.git`) on staging server
   2. cloned `foo.git` into working directory on staging server
   3. cloned `foo.git` into working directory on local development machine
2. Developed locally
3. Pushed changes to `foo.git` repo on staging server
4. On staging server, logged into working directory, and pulled in changes from `foo.git`
5. `lftp`-ed into shared host (like you mention above)
6. Once in shared host, ran: 
       **`mirror -R --only-newer --delete --parallel=10 /source/directory/ /target/directory`**

Notes on the `mirror` command options:

- `-R` - this pushes the `source/directory` to the `target/directory`. (`mirror` pulls in from target to source without this, think `r`everse)
- `—only-newer` - without this option, even if you only changed one file, the `mirror` command will send all the files in the source directory over to the target directory. with this option only the changed (newer) files are transferred over the wire.
- `—delete` - deletes files that are no longer in the source directory but still in the target directory. one of my pushes involved deleting expired assets. without this option, the same files would have stayed put on my shared host after executing the `mirror` command.
- `—parallel=10` - transfers 10 files at once (instead of 1 by default). this made the process much faster

While this is what worked for me, I’m sure there are ways to improve on this. I was grateful for this question and thought i’d share my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync will do this over an FTP connection. You probably already have it installed if you’re on a Unix-like system.

Comment: I may have misremembered; I’m not sure rsync will work over FTP. But if not, there are similar programs that will: https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp